# Connect to Raspberry Database with Android

Tags: java, android, jdbc, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I want to create an app, which connects to a MariaDB on a Raspberry PI but it does not work. I have a Raspberry 4 and it is in the same network as my PC and Android Device. I can access the Raspberry from my Android Device via the Android terminal. When I click on the Button the app crashes. Can please somebody help me? This is the code and errormessages: Jakob

```
package com.example.connect2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new GetData().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        private Exception exception;



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection
                        ("jdbc:mysql://"...", "...", "..."");
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                statement.executeUpdate("insert into hallo values(2);");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

These are the Errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.connect2, PID: 10118
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/security/sasl/SaslClientFactory;
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.authentication.AuthenticationLdapSaslClientPlugin.<clinit>(AuthenticationLdapSaslClientPlugin.java:73)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.loadAuthenticationPlugins(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:246)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:387)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1350)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
        at com.example.connect2.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41)
        at com.example.connect2.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.security.sasl.SaslClientFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~7FsLJrPPrasXfD5dK7SYRw==/com.example.connect2-ZHOEgbksV1I0xZCxR5NTYg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~7FsLJrPPrasXfD5dK7SYRw==/com.example.connect2-ZHOEgbksV1I0xZCxR5NTYg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.authentication.AuthenticationLdapSaslClientPlugin.<clinit>(AuthenticationLdapSaslClientPlugin.java:73) 
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.loadAuthenticationPlugins(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:246) 
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:387) 
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:174) 
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1350) 
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157) 
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953) 
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823) 
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) 
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) 
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218) 
        at com.example.connect2.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41) 
        at com.example.connect2.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:31) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
I/ViewRootImpl@c98ef5[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10118 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Connector/J is [built for Java](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html) and not with Android in mind (the same is true for the [MariaDB Connector](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/) which you probably ought to be using instead). This issue seems to be caused by Android not really being Java. Generally speaking making a direct DB connection from an Android app is a bad idea anyway (among other things because you'd be giving every user of your app direct DB access). Usually you'd have a server that does the DB access.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324619/connecting-to-mariadb-from-an-android-app) reports success with a specific version of the driver, maybe that is worth a try, if you want to go that route.

Comment: You really shouldn't use JDBC from an Android device. Instead built a REST service to mediate between your application and the database. This is generally more secure (it doesn't expose your entire database to the world), and performs better.